# pie chart doesn't show up without error python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a data frame like this:
[image]

and I want to have a pie chart on it. 
I used these 2 ways for drawing a pie chart but they don't work!

```
fig6, ax6 = plt.subplots()
ax6.pie(df6, explode=None, labels=df6.index, autopct='%1.1f%%',
    shadow=False, startangle=90)
ax6.axis('equal') 
plt.ylabel('Twjkhjeet Class Popularity Vs. Day')


plt.show()
```

and

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
labels = 'Negative', 'Positive'
sizes = [9178, 2363]
colors = ['brown', 'lightblue']
explode = (0, 0) 
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
    autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

I dont receive any error from these codes but the plot doesn't show up!

Comment: Does any other plot also not show up? E.g. a line plot? At least the second code is 100% correct, so there might be some other/deeper issue.

Comment: There is a slight chance that the plot windows appear but they go in the background and hide behind the editor or other open windows. To check if that is the case, minimize all the open windows one by one. At some point you might see the open plot windows. It had occurred to a couple of people who asked similar questions and found the same problem. Try it out!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest No, all other plots works well.

Comment: @Bazingaa I am using Jupyter notebook and all of the plots should be shown in one window. Also I have another pie charts and plots which are working properly except this one

Comment: So when you say the plot doesn't show up, what is the output then? In Juypter there is an `Out[<some number>]` field, and next to it the output cell. Does it contain anything? A text? A transparent picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have put `%matplotlib inline`before the `fig6, ax6 = plt.subplots()`.
This is how I could see the plot after running the code.